# Shouldn't IDictionary<TKey, TValue> naturally extend ISet<KeyValuePair<Tkey, TValue>>

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, collections

Shouldn't `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` naturally extend `ISet<KeyValuePair<Tkey, TValue>>`, and what's the reasoning behind it? Is this simply an overlook?

My first thought is that it should, because enumerating `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` naturally blocks write operations. Which to me means that the implementation should already be fairly aligned with an `ISet<T>` implementation. Also, looking at the `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Contains` implementation for `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` and `HashSet<T>` they seem to be functionally identical.

I did notice however that the Java `Map<K,V>` and c++ `std::map` also do not extend their counterpart set interfaces.

If correct then how would you go about a concrete implementation, considering performance and memory usage?

(Not trying to solve any specific problem, just a thought exercise)

Comment: Do set functions like union and intersect make since for a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` type?

Comment: MS doesn't need to justify why something is _not_ implemented.  On the contrary, every feature needs to be justified in terms of total value versus total cost.

Comment: `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is from .NET Framework 2.0. `ISet<T>` is from .NET Framework 4.0. Adding `ISet` as base interface to `IDictionary` would be incompatible change.

Comment: No.  If you have base class "A" and two classes "B" & "C" which inherit "A", "B" & "C" are not identical.

Comment: @juharr Seems to me so, the struct uses default equality and the meaning depends completely on usage. Consider fully indexed entities like in a NoSQL DB. Altought I think that a specialized comparer would eventually be required.

Comment: @PetSerAl That is plain wrong, interfaces are added all the time, exactly like ISet<T> and IReadOnlyXXXX<>

Comment: @TamirDaniely I mean if you create a dictionary why would you want to do set logic on the key-value pair?  You should just want to lookup keys for the most part.

Comment: @jdweng These are interfaces, not clasess

Comment: Interfaces added, but not changed. You can not add new method or new base interface to existing interface.

Comment: No. Dictionary is not a set of key-value pair. For example, in dictionary key pair of (1,2) will replace (1,1), but in a set (1,1) and (1,2) can be in the same collection.

Comment: @TamirDaniely What struct?  You're asking about _interfaces_, no  concrete implementations.  The `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` interface does not include all members of [`ISet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412081.aspx) so no, it cannot "naturally" extend it.

Comment: @DStanley If the contract for IDIctionary means that it always abides by the contract for ISet then it should naturally extend it.

Comment: @juharr I guess I'm mostly thinking about indexing properties of entities. Like foreign keys.

Comment: @TamirDaniely but it doesn't - there are methods in `ISet` that don't exist on `IDictionary`.  Whether they _could_ and/or _should_ be added to `IDictionary` are reasonable questions, but I highly doubt the benefit of the additional methods is worth the cost of a breaking change to a fundamental framework interface.

Comment: @DStanley the point isn't that the methods should be given in any implementation that's an added value, but don't you agree that by contract, an IDictionary<K, V> should fit in any call site for ISet<T>? It is for all considerations a set.

Comment: wouldn't interfaces have same issue as child classes.  Two interface to same Class  Base class are not equivalent.  The complier isn't smart enough to determine the equivalency.

Comment: I mean that interface implies a contract. a dictionary does abide by the set contract, so why isn't it a set. I think ISet<> mashes up definition and specialization in a way that just prevents trivial implementation. Extending Dictionary with ISet or extending HashSet<KVP<..>> with IDictionary will result in an identical implementation for all set operations.

Comment: @TamirDaniely "a dictionary does abide by the set contract" No it doesn't - IDictionary does not have `ExceptWith` and `IntersectWith` among others.  Plus, the equality semantics of `KeyValuePair` are different when used with `IDictionary`.